# How to use ready ui react templates

Tags: reactjs

I'm impressed by airframe and would be happy to implement a similar design for my website (using react). Naturally, using their components and styles it seemed easy. But it's not like react ui library, it's fully implemented demo website you edit for yourself.

It seems to be very hard to delete/edit things to get what I need than to implement from scratch... Also, I'll have a lot of code written with not my style, lots of redundant components and dependencies, foreign build system, you need to support lots of components, even basic, etc. How do you use templates?

Comment: https://material-ui.com/

Comment: checkout https://chakra-ui.com too

Comment: Learning how to use tailwind CSS paired with https://headlessui.dev/ has been great for me.